# How to determine whether my Timer has finished all tasks?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have Google it, whereas all answers i got simplely check only one shceduled task is finished.
What i want is to check whether all tasks are finished or is timer is idle? Is there a good way to manage do it?

```
   val timer =Timer()
        timer.schedule(object:TimerTask(){
            override fun run() {
                Timber.d("task1")
            }
        },1000)

        timer.schedule(object:TimerTask(){
            override fun run() {
                Timber.d("task2")
            }
        },3000)
```

Comment: Did you try `CompletedFuture` or  `Semaphore`？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC there is no built-in functions to check for timer if it has finished all tasks.

One thing you can do is to create an extension function that may count for that.

```kotlin
fun Timer.schedule(delay: Long, counter: AtomicInteger, task: TimerTask.() -> Unit) {
    counter.incrementAndGet()
    schedule(object : TimerTask{
        override fun run() {
            task()
            counter.decrementAndGet()
        }
    }, delay)
}
```

Now call the schedule by passing a AtomicInteger.

```kotlin
val timer = Timer()
val counter = AtomicInteger(0)

timer.schedule(1_000L, counter) {
    Timber.d("task1")
}
timer.schedule(3_000L, counter) {
    Timber.d("task2")
}

// check somewhere
val remaining = counter.get()
if (remaining == 0) {
    // timer has finished all the tasks
} else {
    // timer has tasks remaining
    println("Timer has $remaining tasks")
}
```

However the major drawback of this synthetic sugar is that if you use the actual `Timer.schedule` defined in the class, then you have no way of determining how much tasks are alive. Because std-lib does not implement the functionality anyway.